# create XML using groovy issue

Tags: xml, groovy

i want to create a XML and save it in a file. below is part of code

```
  def fileWriter = new FileWriter("c:/temp/test.xml")
  def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(fileWriter).event {
    event ("xmlns" : "http://www.hp.com/2009/software/opr/data_model") {
      state("closed")
    }
//    fileWriter.close();        
  }
  fileWriter.close();
```

this works fine and create a XML file in c:\temp\ Directory.

and this is how it Looks.

```
<event>
<event xmlns='http://www.hp.com/2009/software/opr/data_model'>
<state>closed</state>
</event>
</event>
```

but what i want is just

```
<event xmlns='http://www.hp.com/2009/software/opr/data_model'>
<state>closed</state>
</event>
```

How do i avoid first and last   from the XML Output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the additional `event`:

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

def fileWriter = new FileWriter("c:/temp/test.xml")

new MarkupBuilder(fileWriter).event("xmlns": "http://www.hp.com/2009/software/opr/data_model") {
    state("closed")
}

fileWriter.close();
```

Comment: Thanks. i worked. i was trying to remove first Event tag which was giving error.

Answer (score 2):

You call event twice, so you get two event tags.
Call it once and you only get one.
Besidest that I'd recommend using `withWriter()` like

```
new File(/c:\temp\test.xml/).withWriter {
  def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(it).event(xmlns: 'http://www.hp.com/2009/software/opr/data_model') {
    state 'closed'
  }
}
```

No need to manually close the writer then.